# Two drives with LUKS+LVM, only the first one can mount

Tags: lvm, luks, xubuntu

I have the following setup:

```
sda (new installation)
  sda1
  sda2
  sda3 (LVM-LUKS)
    root
    swap

sdb (old installation)
  sdb1
  sdb2
  sdb5 (LVM-LUKS)
    root (old)
    swap
```

The goal is to have `sda3`->`root` as `/` and `sdb5`->`root` as `/home/user/other` mounted at boot time.

Currently `sda` operates correctly during the boot, but `sdb` refuses to mount root or see its swap.

I have currently added a second line to `/etc/crypttab`, now it looks like this:

```
sda3_crypt UUID=uuid-for-sda3 none luks,discard
sdb5_crypt UUID=uuid-for-sda3 none luks,discard
```

This has resulted in the appearance of `/dev/mapper/sdb5_crypt`, and it links correctly to a newly-appeared `/dev/dm-3`. However, unlike `sda3` it doesn't "expand" its partition table.

I have tried to boot into a live-usb, there i can mount either of the drives successfully; but i cannot mount both at the same time. This leads me to believe that it maybe a problem with some internal naming scheme, for example both maybe trying to usurp "xubuntu--vg-root" as the mapper name, and thus only the first one succeeds in that task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the conflict in the name of LVM, both were titled `xubuntu--vg`. To resolve this issue one needs to first rename the virtual group with `vgrename`.